# How to download a package for offline installation?

Tags: 10.04, command-line, apt, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

```
    sudo apt-get install {x}     ex: X = ghdl
```

I want download the package "X" to my USB . How can I do that ?

Second, my computer doesn't have internet, so how do I install it on my computer?

*EDIT: So my question is this:*

- How to download the packages from the Ubuntu Desktop having the internet connection without installing it there?
- How do I copy the now downloaded package on to my USB drive? (specific location of the downloaded package once it's downloaded)
- What command am I supposed to execute at home to install the software from the USB once I am on the computer that doesn't have the internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing `apt-get -d install <packagename>` should do the trick. The `-d` flag tells apt-get to only download the package and not install it. Adding `-o=dir::cache=/mnt` should tell apt to download it into /mnt, but you might need to fiddle about with that to make it work properly (it might want directories laid out like an apt-cache, it's been a while since I've done this).